# variable does not print in a function as expected

Tags: linux, bash

I have this:

And I was hoping that in `f1()` I will be able to access the variable `$pid`. But my script does not print the value from function `f1()`. Can you explain that ?

```
#!/bin/sh

f1()
{
    echo in f1 pid is $pid
}


f2()
{
    sleep 1
    f1
}

f2 &

pid=$!

echo f2 bg pid is $pid
```

output

```
f2 bg pid is 15095
in f1 pid is
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `pid` in the parent process after you've forked `f2` into its own process, thus there is no way to access it across processes. You can access your own process' pid as `$$`.

Comment: Or the parent process as $PPID, depending on what you're trying to express.

Comment: A subshell retains the same values of `$$` and `$PPID`, so that may not be what you want. One way to avoid this is to start a new instance of the shell.

Comment: A subshell executed via a fork would _never_ retain the same `$$` and `$PPID` values as its parent shell, because it would make absolutely no sense.